# generating table from *.geojson

Tags: html-table, leaflet, geojson

I'm generating a HTML-table with data from a geojson-file using leaflet. It works fine, but only if I do not delete the "alert" from the following code. Otherwise the data are displaied without table. How to solve this?

```
   $.ajax({url:"wind.geojson"}).done(function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        L.geoJson(data, 
            {pointToLayer: MarkerStyle1});
        });
alert();

    function MarkerStyle1 (feature,latlng) {
    ...
    document.writeln ("<td width='40'><div align='center'>" ,feature.properties.title, "</div></td>\n");
    ...
    };
```

Comment: This is usually an indication that the function is called before the data are loaded. But your code not look like that. Try to add the `MarkerStyle1` function into the done function, or above the ajax call.

Comment: Unfortunately both actions do not work.

Comment: hmm can you pls send me the geojson data

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any possibility here to upload a file, it's 200kb. It's to find here: [1](https://aachen-hat-energie.de/wind.geojson) The file works well, when I show the objects on a map.

[2](https://aachen-hat-energie.de/gpx/windanlagen.php) shows on older version of the site, where the table is generated with php (done by a friend, I do not use php).

Perhaps it is a problem, that I do not have a "map", no "map.addLayer()" in this code!?

I now realized that the problem is caused by the asynchronous working of AJAX. I changed the code to

```
$.ajax({url:"wind.geojson", async: false})
```

Now it is working without the "alert()"-line!